# pagination with live search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, livesearch

So far, i have done creating report with paging. 
sample code index.php:

```
<div class='web'>    
    <h1>Data Order Notaris</h1>
        <div id="page_data"></div>
            <span class="flash"></span>
        </div>
```

and use script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    change_page('0');
                });
                    function change_page(page_id){
                        $(".flash").show();
                        $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html('Loading <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
                        var dataString = 'page_id='+ page_id;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "paging.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                    success: function(result){
                                        $(".flash").hide();
                                        $("#page_data").html(result);
                                    }
                            });
                    }
```

my file for show paging is paging.php
my problem when using live search. i am trying add input type in index.php

add input script:

```
<input type='text' name='search' placeholder='search' />
```

i think it doesn't need form and submit button.
how to post value from input name='search' to paging.php for filter data report?

is it need more function or using function change_page? i am still confuse with logic. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give Input in this way:

```
 <input type='text' Id="search_box" name='search' placeholder='search' />
```

Then using js you can fetch this field's value

**So your js code will be as:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    change_page('0');
                });
                    function change_page(page_id){
                        //To get the field value
                        var search_val = $("#search_box").val();
                        $(".flash").show();
                        $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html('Loading <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
                        var dataString = 'page_id='+ page_id+'&search='+search_val;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "paging.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                    success: function(result){
                                        $(".flash").hide();
                                        $("#page_data").html(result);
                                    }
                            });
                    }
```

Then make the appropriate query in your paging.php :)

Comment: thanks for help. from that script i know that value for filter is save in variable search_val. then, how can i get value in paging.php ?

<?php
$search_val=search_val;
$query="SELECT 
 idNoon,notaris,noon,cabang,nama,proses,tanggalOn,tanggalCair,keterangan 
 FROM 
  tblNotaris,tblOrderNotaris
 where 
  tblNotaris.idnotaris=tblOrderNotaris.idnotaris
  and name like '%$search_val%'
 order by
  idNoon desc";
?>

Comment: You can get value as `$search_val=$_POST['search']` as you are sending data in post @StevenSugiartoWijaya

Comment: sorry, still not working. is that function jquery automatic? or need trigger? when input data <input type='text' Id="search_box" name='search' placeholder='search' /> paging not change.

Comment: No you have to call this `change_page` function on paging button click with arguments like `change_page('10'),change_page('20'), etc.`. Then you need to write code for particular page in `paging.php`